# Send text from list into input form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a search tool for looking up images on Google. The idea is to have a search suffix, for instance bark or flower and the adding a name from list (plant names). I've gotten so far that I managed to make search bars that have a static suffix in them, but I am struggling to get the names onClick into the bars. Ideally the names will just be added to the suffix, but for now I can only get them to overwrite.
EDIT: I want the names on the list the be combined with whatever search suffix.

Here is my code so far:
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ckukbvLn/)

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/images?q=“ target="_blank">
    <input id="addons1" value="bark+" name="q">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<a onclick="document.getElementById('addons1').setAttribute('value','bark+Fagus sylvatica');">Fagus sylvatica</a> <br>
```

The function I am using is document.getElementById but maybe it would be better to have a general function that allows all items from the list to be clicked into the forms, or maybe just one form and then have an option to add suffixes.
Hope it is understandable what I want to achieve.

Best regards

Comment: First, fix the closing quotes of your `action` in the `form` tag!

Comment: Bloody Mavericks update made me do it! You are correct

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of the solution!

One input form is enough in my opinion.

Then made some CSS changes which seem required for layout.

finally, we can get all the `a` tag elements from the `div` with class `keywords` then add an event `onclick` which will get the text value inside the `a` tag and append it to the input elements value!

Please let me know if there are any issues with the below snippet!

```js
for ( var i of document.getElementsByClassName('keywords')[0].children){
 i.onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('addons1').value += this.innerHTML + "+";
  }
}
```

```css
.keywords a{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.google.com/images?q=" target="_blank">
  <input id="addons1" value="bark+" name="q">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<br>
<br>
<div class="keywords">

  <a>Fagus sylvatica</a>
  <a>Abies alba</a>
  <a>Picea abies</a>
  <a>Picea omorika</a>
  <a>Larix decidua</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Much better solution! Now I can make a list of both items and suffixes and then they can be pressed to search the combination I want.

Comment: @EmilNøjgaardPetersen You're welcome, Hope your question is completely resolved!

Comment: When I try it the debugger says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined"? Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: @EmilNøjgaardPetersen have you defined this wrapper div `<div class="keywords">` also can you share the code with the issue on JSFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/21s8bowm/ but it works there? I put the javascript in the head section of the html page in a <script></script> isn't that correct?

Comment: @EmilNøjgaardPetersen You're welcome, hope we can close the question!